# Issue running SpecFlow under Docker

Tags: .net, docker, specflow

I have an API test suite written using SpecFlow. When run from VS, it works fine. I've tried creating docker image and running `dotnet test` command there, but I get following error:

```
PS /source/DotNetApiTests> dotnet test -s ./example.runsettings  
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  SpecFlowFeatureFiles: **/*.feature
  -> Using specflow.json
**/*.feature : error : Generation error: Message: Could not find a part of the path '/source/DotNetApiTests/**/*.feature'. [/source/DotNetApiTests/DotNetApiTests.csproj]
**/*.feature : error :  [/source/DotNetApiTests/DotNetApiTests.csproj]
**/*.feature : error : AppDomain Information:  [/source/DotNetApiTests/DotNetApiTests.csproj]
**/*.feature : error :  Name: dotnet [/source/DotNetApiTests/DotNetApiTests.csproj]
**/*.feature : error :  BaseDirectory: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.411/ [/source/DotNetApiTests/DotNetApiTests.csproj]
**/*.feature : error :  [/source/DotNetApiTests/DotNetApiTests.csproj]
```

I created docker image using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0` as a base. I already excluded common-sense issues like wrong file path, file permissions and similar. Any ideas what could be the issue?

I've tried to find a way to specify features path explicitly (thought that Linux has issue with `**` part of path), but I couldn't find a way to do this. Any help here?

**EDIT:**

Here's the example.runsettings used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <NUnit>
        <TestOutputXml>../../../TestResults</TestOutputXml>
        <StopOnError>false</StopOnError>
    </NUnit>
    <RunConfiguration>
        <TestSessionTimeout>1800000</TestSessionTimeout>
    </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

Comment: Are all the tests really under `*root*/source`?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the contents of the runsettings file? Typically you load test assemblies (DLL files) not feature files or feature.cs files.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes, they are.